# SWT - MessageDialog - Shells

Tags: java, dialog, swt

I have an operations class that has no gui. The class basically does data management. The class is called from a method in my Main GUI. The problem I am having is with displaying messages to the user if something fails. I am using `MessageDialog`, but it keeps failing at runtime. I think the issue is with Shell. When I try to use `null` as the shell.

```
MessageDialog.openError(null, "Printer Error Message", "Error getting print reply file.");
```

The error is null pointer exception

```
MessageDialog.openError(Display.getCurrent().getActiveShell() etc
```

The error is null pointer exception

```
MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell()
```

The error is invalid thread access

1. Being this is not a GUI class, do I have to pass in the shell from the GUI parent?
2. Can I just create a shell in the class and then use that?

Comment: I ended up using both of your answers.  I was not importing the correct Shell class.  I also had to use Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {  to avoid the thread issues.  And not sure how to select both as answers

Comment: You can't select both as answers. You can upvote both and then select one which you will accept as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fix the `ERROR_THREAD_INVALID_ACCESS` error with [`Display.syncExec`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#syncExec%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [`Display.asyncExec`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display.html#asyncExec%28java.lang.Runnable%29) . Try with:

```
Display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
    void run() {
        MessageDialog.openError(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell()...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want:

```
MessageDialog.openError(new Shell(), "Printer Error Message", "Error getting print reply file.");
```

Just create a new [`Shell`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html#Shell%28%29) and pass it to the `MessageDialog`.

Comment: @jkteater The constructor `new Shell()` does exists. Are you sure you imported the correct `Shell` class?

Comment: @jkteater it exists - http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FShell.html

Answer (score 2):

Few important points to consider.

1. First of all, do not mix Data Management classes(models) with UI.
2. Have a utility class and methods to show errors/info messages.
3. always access UI widgets in UI thread. Use `Display.getDefault().asyncExec()` or `syncExce()`
4. Check `Display.getDefault().getActiveShell()` to pass it to the
   dialog first, if it is null, create one and pass it.